# If table contains a key with specific value

Tags: lua, lua-table

It might be a bit confusing, but I have a table, for example, called `Ant`.

This table, contains a bunch of other (unnamed) tables. These tables represent ants, and hold values.

Kind of like this:

```
Ant = {
  {age=3,speed=10},
  {age=6,speed=7}
}
```

My question is, how would I check if any of the unnamed table inside of the Ant table contains a specific value to `age`.

So, for example, I'd like to check if any of my ants are aged 3 years old.

I hope I was clear enough, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through the table and check:

```
for i, v in ipairs(Ant) do
  if v.age == 3 then
    print( i )
  end
end
```

It'll [print the index](http://codepad.org/3bX0HnGM) at which your 3 year old **ants** are stored.

Comment: Alright, what if I had a mother values, and it needed to be changed. So I loop through all of the ants, but I only want to change one of them.

Comment: @DoorKnob Can you give an example? Explain the situation?

Comment: @DoorKnob `break` after `print`

Comment: Thanks, user has it right. but, for clarifying, let's say none of my ants are mothers. I'd like to have one a mother. I don't want to change all of them, just one.

Comment: @DoorKnob You can reference the Ant with the index: `Ant[i].isMother = true`

Comment: @DoorKnob Or (to apply the SPOT rule) set `Ant.mother` to one of ants: `Ant.mother = Ant[i]`. (`Ant` should probably be `Ants` to denote an array instead of a single instance)

Comment: @DoorKnob please extend your question to include the mother part, it'll make this QA easier for everyone to follow. I'm tempted to answer that you would do v.mother=true instead of print(i). However you should indicate in your extended question whether you want to change the first ant found (with age>3) to be a mother, could there be more than one that have required age?

Comment: The `break` is what I needed, in this certain situation. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to check the value of `age` in each sub-table, building a custom iterator is another way:

```
function age_iter(t)
    local i = 0
    return function() 
               i = i + 1 
               return t[i] and t[i].age 
           end
end
```

To iterate over all the `age` value would be:

```
for age in age_iter(Ant) do
  print(age)
end
```

It's easy to modify it to check if one of the `age` value is equal to `3`.